# implement boolean function using half adders and not gates

Tags: boolean, combinators

I received this question from my lecturer and i am stuck.

F=ca+b'a'

implement this function using no more than 3 H.A (half adder) and 3 NOT gates.

i succeed to get a'b' and ac 
and still had 1 HA and 1 NOT gate.

I have difficulties creating the OR gate for those two.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: up, can somebody answer it please it is really important.

Answer (score 0):

Use De Morgan's law and convert the expression in the following form `:- ((ca)'(b'a')')'`. Assuming that complements of the Literals are available.
[The actual implementation of the circuit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDI9a.jpg)